# What is the cataclysm that befalls Earth in Wool?

Tags: wool, hugh-howey

In the [*Wool* series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wool_(series)); specifically, *Wool 6: First Shift*,

> it is said that the world ends with atomic bombs.

The landscape of the world definitely jives with this.

However, whenever someone goes out into the world,

> their protective suit is immediately attacked by something in the air and slowly disintegrates. *First Shift* makes mention of nano-technology or poison, but I don't recall if that was ever confirmed or not.

Does the series reveal what is the villain in the air?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The nanos wipe out humans in a controlled, timed, DNA-based attack. The bombs served three purposes (and there were only three bombs): They ushered the survivors into the silos; they provided the initial (and fuzzy) legends about the destruction of all things; and they were the trauma that allowed the subsequent regimen of medication to divide the forgotten past from their new future.

Comment: Wow.  Answered directly by the author...  Hi, Hugh!

Comment: Wicked awesome! Thanks for the answer!