# What was the purpose of the servers in each silo?

Tags: wool, hugh-howey

According to Dust, each silo's IT level houses 50 servers arranged in the same spatial pattern as the 50 silos themselves. But why? The diggers were already pointed in the right direction to escape the bad nano zone at the end of the 500 years.

The servers also store information on each silo's inhabitants, and Silo 1's servers use that to rank the top silo, which will be the only one whose inhabitants are released. But exactly what is that information?

- Population birth rates/fertility? It is implied that there is an abnormally high number of twins being born -- or is that just a side-effect of exposure to the good nanos? But would a high birth rate really be all that desirable when first settling a pristine world? Wouldn't the survivors want to establish infrastructure first?
- Some kind of natural resistance or immunity against the bad nanos?
- Mental/psychological acceptance of the current state of the world? There is evidently some kind of advanced polygraph technology built into the communications system. Did the original Pact members want the survivors to be as far disconnected from the original world as possible, to reduce the chances of bad nanos being redeveloped?

Do the servers have any other purpose? Do they store redundant digital copies of the Legacy?

I'm sure any answers to these questions will involve some speculation -- unless the [answer comes from Hugh Howey himself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/20188/42682).

Comment: This seems like you're asking a couple of different questions; generally we'd prefer you ask them separately, so we can answer each one independently.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no Nanos except on Silo 1, and where they "leaked" into the other silo. The servers are simply managing the populations to prevent inbreeding.